# Consider the linear transformation $L:R^n\to R^n$ defined by $L\left(X\right)=AX$, then $A$ is diagonalizable iff the matrix of $L$ is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was asked to study the following corollary [image]

I could only understand up to theorem 3, does anyone know what the name of this corollary is and if there is clearer proof online?

Comment: Any diagonalizable transformation has a diagonal matrix with respect to its basis of eigenvectors, and a transformation is diagonalizable if and only if it has a basis of eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a pretty straightforward result. You have to first understand what do you mean by Diagonalization. It means that the matrix representing the linear transformation (with a suitable basis) is a diagonal matrix. Note that if you change the basis the matrix representing the transformation will likely change. There is another interpretation of Diagonalization which says that a linear transformation is diagonalize if the eigen spaces corresponding to the eigen vales cumulatively span the range of the transformation. This corollary shows that the two are equivalent.

Comment: Is there a clearer proof?

Comment: Well, Anonymous, it would help if you were to give some hint as to what exactly you find unclear.

Comment: Are you still there, Anon?